df /dev/sda or df /dev/"partitions used by lvm" is showing incorrect size
There are so many topics about the df command but I cannot see any answer. I have a problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with sda3 and sda4 partitions together with volume sda. While fdisk and lsblk are showing correct values, df is not.
As you can see below (at the very bottom) df /dev/sda3 or df /dev/sda4 or finally df /dev/sda are not in line with fdisk or lsblk (presented below at the top).
How can I fix this?
I was using sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root and resize2fs to get to this stage and actually I have improved as it now seems that df -h is showing correct values. It is only these 3 commands that are not in line (showing some 32GB):
df -h /dev/sda3 or df -h /dev/sda4 or finally df -h /dev/sda
Command output:
user1@prod01:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0  250G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0  1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
├─sda3                      8:3    0  117G  0 part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  247G  0 lvm  /
└─sda4                      8:4    0  130G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  247G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
loop0                       7:0    0 55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2823
loop1                       7:1    0 63.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/2434
loop2                       7:2    0 73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1663
loop3                       7:3    0 11.9M  1 loop /snap/kubectl/3164
loop4                       7:4    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop5                       7:5    0  132M  1 loop /snap/docker/2932
loop6                       7:6    0   64M  1 loop /snap/core20/2264
loop7                       7:7    0  177M  1 loop /snap/microk8s/6089
loop8                       7:8    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/29619
loop9                       7:9    0 49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
loop10                      7:10   0 74.3M  1 loop /snap/core22/1621
loop11                      7:11   0 38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
user1@prod01:~$



user1@prod01:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3557335F-1A0B-495D-B519-A7F4026BE14E

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2203647   2201600  1.1G EFI System
/dev/sda2    2203648   6397951   4194304    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3    6397952 251656191 245258240  117G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  251656192 524287966 272631775  130G Linux filesystem
user1@prod01:~$



user1@prod01:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              6.3G  5.2M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  243G   31G  202G  14% /
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  212M  1.6G  12% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
user1@prod01:~$



user1@prod01:~$ df -h /dev/sda1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
user1@prod01:~$ df -h /dev/sda2
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       2.0G  212M  1.6G  12% /boot
user1@prod01:~$ df -h /dev/sda3
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
user1@prod01:~$ df -h /dev/sda4
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
user1@prod01:~$ df -h /dev/sda
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
user1@prod01:~$


df doesn't report the size of your /-filesystem in this cases (/dev/sda3, /dev/sda4), just look at the mount point. That happens probably due to your raid configuration or LVM, these devices are somehow managed by udev. I don't know details about that, just my observation.
